# Next steps for self-taught student aspiring to be a professional

Tags: piano

As a self taught pianist and composer under 13 years old, I can play many difficult pieces by different composers like Liszt, Rachmaninoff, Chopin, and many others. And I'm wondering: can I actually be a concert pianist myself? So let’s assume I have the skills the be a concert pianist, how can I get started? If there’s any concert pianist, some tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a little read of auto/biographies of concert pianists. There will be a lot of insight into their early formative lives. Lots of information there.

Comment: A lot of self taught pianist usually have huge flaws in their playings that they do not notice/know how to rectify without a teacher, voicing, articulation, pedalling, rubato, etc. I highly advice you at least seek some opinions from someone with classical training

Answer (score 5):

The best way is to get a teacher. You can get several things from a teacher (private or associated with an educational institution): some advanced techniques that may not be obvious, a wider exposer to the piano literature, contacts (most teachers know someone who knows someone), exposure (teachers often organize recitals for their students, shows of both the students and the teacher), expressive playing (it's not enough to hit the notes, one must know what the unwritten tradition is for each piece.)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question is of course yes you can. There is the traditional method which includes years of study with instructors who specialize in practices and focus specifically on classical interpretations of the music. That is just one way to go. It is entirely possible to make your own way if you learn how to promote yourself to the public and have a good sense of how business is conducted, and know how to meet the people who can give you needed support for your endeavors. You need to realize that going you own way or choosing the traditional way, either way, there will be numerous times when you will feel you've run into a brick wall and a dead end. Everyone I know has this happen to them. It's only the end if you think it is. If instead you analyze the situation carefully, you will most likely be able to move forward towards your goal with the added advantage of the newly acquired knowledge that brick walls seem to present for us. If it is what you want to do in your life, learn everything you can about it and put it into practice. Chances are better than not you'll get there, but there are never any absolute assurances.